# Add pagination to simple jQuery Carousel

Tags: jquery, pagination, carousel

I have created a simple jQuery circular (infinite) Carousel. I want to add pagination to my script so that there is an indicator of which slide is which in the cycle. My jQuery code is below:

```
jQuery.fn.carousel = function(previous, next, options){
var sliderList = jQuery(this).children()[0];

if (sliderList) {
    var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth("true"),
    elmnts = jQuery(sliderList).children(),
    numElmts = elmnts.length,
    sizeFirstElmnt = increment,
    shownInViewport = Math.round(jQuery(this).width() / sizeFirstElmnt),
    firstElementOnViewPort = 1,
    isAnimating = false;

    for (i = 0; i < shownInViewport; i++) {
        jQuery(sliderList).css('width',(numElmts+shownInViewport)*increment + increment + "px");
        jQuery(sliderList).append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
    }

    jQuery(previous).click(function(event){
        if (!isAnimating) {
            if (firstElementOnViewPort == 1) {
                jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "-" + numElmts * sizeFirstElmnt + "px");
                firstElementOnViewPort = numElmts;
            }
            else {
                firstElementOnViewPort--;
            }

            jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                left: "+=" + increment,
                y: 0,
                queue: true
            }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
            isAnimating = true;
        }

    });

    jQuery(next).click(function(event){
        if (!isAnimating) {
            if (firstElementOnViewPort > numElmts) {
                firstElementOnViewPort = 2;
                jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "0px");
            }
            else {
                firstElementOnViewPort++;
            }
            jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                left: "-=" + increment,
                y: 0,
                queue: true
            }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
            isAnimating = true;
        }
    });
}
};
```

and html markup is here:

```
<div id="viewport">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- END VIEWPORT-->

<div class="buttons">
     <a id="prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
     <a id="next"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to kow how I would implement a pagination system. Any hep or guidance would be great. You can see my code in action here:
http://www.samskirrow.com/projects/carousel

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic idea of what you're hoping to achieve, but the way I would go around this is for each item that is in your carousel to append an element to another menu, and then link each one to the relevant element in the slider. For example [please see this VERY basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKqZZ/2/).

To add the elements

```
count = 0;
$('#cara .item').each(function () {
    count++;
    li = '<li id="' + count + '"> Page ' + count + '</li>';
    $('.page ul').append(li);
});
```

And for each element on click animate to the item in your carousel.

```
$('.page ul li').on('click', function () {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.item').animate({opacity:0});
    $('.item:nth-of-type('+id+')').animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
});
```

As I said this is a simple version of what you're trying to achieve but is an idea that might help you.